# My div background color won't show up

Tags: html, css, background-color

I'm building a basic webpage to practice HTML, but am having trouble right off the bat.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=“eng”>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link type=“text/css” rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Greg’s Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ID=“header”>Hello</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
#header {
  height: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #4A7B6F;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #9EAEB3;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Now for some reason, when I preview this HTML file on my computer it just looks like this:  Hello.  I've looked up syntax everywhere and I can't see anything I am doing wrong.

Comment: your id quotes are wrong, it should be the one on the right of semi-colon...

Comment: In HTML5, consider using semantic elements: instead of `<div id="header">` try `<header>`. Then your CSS is: `header {...}`. Your code becomes easier to read, is simpler (fewer `id="..."`!) and works well with accessibility clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there are a few things that are probably causing this. First, you have two `html` tags. second, `ID` is capitalized (not sure if that would cause any issues), and third you're not using ASCII quotes. `“` (character code 8220) is not the same as `"` (character code 34).

Note that that quote issue most commonly comes from copying from a text editor, like Word. If you look at what you put, you'll see that the ID isn't the only thing with the wrong type of quotes.

Your code with those things fixed works:

```css
#header {
  height: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #4A7B6F;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #9EAEB3;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Greg's Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ID="header">Hello</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah thanks.  I was using the regular text editor on my Mac, and not copying and pasting, so I guess I'll have to find a new editor):

Comment: Hmm, strange that Mac doesn't have a pure ASCII editor like Windows. This might be a useful place to start looking: http://alternativeto.net/software/notepad-plus-plus/?platform=mac

Comment: Thank you, I will check out that link!

Answer (score 4):

Change the quotes for id. Also change the case of ID.

Instead of

```
 <div ID=“header”>Hello</div>
```

use

```
<div id="header">Hello</div>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/586/

Comment: How do I do that instead of my normal quotes?  On the HTML lessons I learned normal quotes worked.

Comment: Refer the explanation provided by David in his answer. The quotes you used are different than those used in CSS

Comment: Look closely - they are not 'normal' double quotes. The “ (which have a slight curve on them) are sometimes used on web pages to show quoting  and are different from actual double quote " which is straight. Its probably a cut and paste issue from code taken on a web page.  Just make sure that ALL the double quotes in you code have been over typed with the correct ones

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are wrong...
Check this fiddle

```
<div ID="header">Hello</div>
```

Demo    https://jsfiddle.net/qq5sk3nf/

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied the code from somewhere or typed it? The double-quotes used is incorrect. Use the ASCII quotes (the ones we use normally by pressing the Shift key and the quote key)

Make changes as below:

Change this `<html lang=“eng”>`
to `<html lang="eng">`

Change this `<link type=“text/css” rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`
to

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Change this `<div ID=“header”>Hello</div>`
to `<div ID="header">Hello</div>`

Your code would work fine after that. See your output below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the line the below line:

```
   <div ID=“header”>Hello</div>
```

By this

```
  <div id="header">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure every quote you use in an html tag isn't curly-ish. On a standard keyboard, the quote symbol is what you get when you hold shift and press the key between the colon and the main enter key. Also, using en for the value for lang stands for standard english. The working code is below.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Greg’s Page</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div ID="header">Hello</div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Your style.css file (must be located in same folder as above HTML file):

```
    #header {
    height: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #4A7B6F;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #9EAEB3;
    margin: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3okp9j91/)

Fixed code:

`<div id="header">Hello</div>`

Problems:

1. id cannot be in caps
2. You cannot use “ quotes. You must use ".

Answer (score 0):

```
Change the quotes for div id.

Wrong use---

<div ID=“header”>Hello</div>

Right use---

<div id="header">Hello</div>

then write css #header
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead, I think the problem is because you used background-color

color: #4A7B6F;

Comment: Doesn't color just change the font color?

Comment: That changes the color of the text, not the background color as desired.